# Insert row in external Google sheet on form submit

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google form where a question is asked, "Has a flyer already been created" and if the answer is "No" then I need to gather certain bits of data from the form submittal and insert a new row in an external sheet. [I have a drawing here.](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1x_UsFJmXB9DTotkvzous9lsIfGRZQkaHJQ4QLrKIf_g/edit?usp=sharing)

The Sheet #1 ([the sheet with the form is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdEJIWjEtLWRTQ1dYdUVvNXFQS1VsQnc&usp=sharing)) 
The Sheet #2 ([sheet that will get a new conditional row submit is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ai_2YLvaQba0dHA2bTdtd0pnTTZQcnRldjJXcjFjZHc&usp=sharing))

I've started a script to do this insert but I am don't have the knowledge to finish the script.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var name = e.values[1];
  var phone = e.values[2];
  var classTitle = e.values[4];
  var dueDate = e.values[7];

  //when there is field 19 in this sheet answer is No (There has not yet been a flyer created) this is when the insert would happen and the Field 19 answer is not something that needs to be carried to the new row in the external sheet)
  var formCreated = e.values[19];

  var workType = "Flyer" ;
  var contextNote = "This job was imported from a Org Learning's Class Reservation Form and followup will be required for clarification" ;
  var destinationSpreadSheetKey = "0Ai_2YLvaQba0dHA2bTdtd0pnTTZQcnRldjJXcjFjZHc";
  var destinationSheet = "Work_Orders";

  //if the answer to variable formCreated is "Yes", then halt Else continue with script
```

Will someone help me with this script?  I have a map of the fields in the drawing.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: We are close to a solution in the Google Forums.  I will add the solution here as to provide an answer to whomever might have a similar need.

Answer (score 2):

The final working code, nicely commented.

```
/**
* Copies from separate source ranges and pastes at first empty row on target sheet
*/

function CopyIt() {
var source_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var target_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Ai_2YLvaQba0dHA2bTdtd0pnTTZQcnRldjJXcjFjZHc");


// Get source and target sheets - can be the same or different
var sourcesheet = source_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
var targetsheet = target_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Work_Orders");

//Get row of last form submission
var source_last_row = sourcesheet.getLastRow();

// Check for answer to Flyer Created? If Yes, end now. If not Yes, i.e. No, continue.
var check = sourcesheet.getRange("T" + (source_last_row)).getValue();
if (check != 'Yes') {

    // Get the source ranges
    // TimeStamp
    var source_range1 = sourcesheet.getRange("A" + (source_last_row));

    //Name
    var source_range2 = sourcesheet.getRange("B" + (source_last_row));


    //Phone Number
    var source_range3 = sourcesheet.getRange("C" + (source_last_row));


    //Class Name/Title
    var source_range4 = sourcesheet.getRange("E" + (source_last_row));


    //First Session
    var source_range5 = sourcesheet.getRange("H" + (source_last_row));

    var source_range1_values = source_range1.getValues();
    var source_range2_values = source_range2.getValues();
    var source_range3_values = source_range3.getValues();
    var source_range4_values = source_range4.getValues();
    var source_range5_values = source_range5.getValues();

    // Get the last row on the target sheet
    var last_row = targetsheet.getLastRow();

    // Set the target ranges on target sheet
    //TimeStamp
    var target1 = targetsheet.getRange("A" + (last_row + 1));

    //Name
    var target2 = targetsheet.getRange("H" + (last_row + 1));

    //Phone
    var target3 = targetsheet.getRange("I" + (last_row + 1));

    //Your Project Name
    var target4 = targetsheet.getRange("K" + (last_row + 1));

    //Final Due Date
    var target5 = targetsheet.getRange("M" + (last_row + 1));

    //The next two are defined in script
    var target6 = targetsheet.getRange("O" + (last_row + 1));
    var target7 = targetsheet.getRange("Q" + (last_row + 1));

    // Put the data from the source sheet into the target sheet, after adding a new row
    targetsheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
    target1.setValues(source_range1_values);
    target2.setValues(source_range2_values);
    target3.setValues(source_range3_values);
    target4.setValues(source_range4_values);
    target5.setValues(source_range5_values);

    // Just using the text to put this data, so there is no source range above.   
    target6.setValue('Flyer');
    target7.setValue('This job was imported from a Org Learning\'s Class Reservation Form and followup will be required for clarification');


 }
}
```